# Why is the root filesystem so small on a clean Fedora 37 install

Tags: linux, fedora, partition, lvm

Fresh install on a machine that has two disks:

```
1TB HDD
150GB SSD
```

I installed Fedora on the latter but for some reason only 15GB of it is allocated for the root filesytem:

```
NAME                   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
sda                      8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─sda1                   8:1    0   579M  0 part 
└─sda2                   8:2    0 930.9G  0 part /run/media/richard/12a41467-0624-427c-a60b-86863514358a
sdb                      8:16   0 149.1G  0 disk 
├─sdb1                   8:17   0   600M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sdb2                   8:18   0     1G  0 part /boot
└─sdb3                   8:19   0 147.5G  0 part 
  └─fedora_fedora-root 253:0    0    15G  0 lvm  /
sdc                      8:32   1     0B  0 disk 
sdd                      8:48   1     0B  0 disk 
sde                      8:64   1     0B  0 disk 
sr0                     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom  
zram0                  252:0    0     8G  0 disk [SWAP]
```

First question - is this normal to not use the whole thing?

Second question - what is the right set of commands to follow to make more of it available?

**Update**

I was able to increase the size using:

```
lvextend -L +10G /dev/mapper/fedora_fedora-root
```

But is this the best solution?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the same thing is usually seen on fresh Ubuntu installations.

Comment: 15 GB?   Luxury !   Back in my day we had two boot floppies, and we liked it !

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is [default behaviour of Fedora Server](https://lists.fedoraproject.org/archives/list/server@lists.fedoraproject.org/thread/D7ZK7SILYDYAATRFS6BFWZQWS6KSRGDG/) -- the root filesystem will be 15 GiB and rest of the disk space is left unused for the user to either resize the root logical volume or use for different use case (for `/var` or virtualization etc.). If you want a different storage layout, you need to use the [custom partitioning](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/fedora/f36/install-guide/install/Installing_Using_Anaconda/#sect-installation-gui-manual-partitioning) in the installer and create the mountpoints manually .

One of the reasons is that the XFS filesystem used by Fedora Server (and only server, Workstation and other flavours use btrfs) cannot be shrunk so if the installer uses the entire free space, it will be really hard to change the default layout.

If you want to resize your root filesystem you can use `lvextend -L+<size> --resizefs fedora_fedora/root`. Where `<size>` can be for example `50G` for 50 GiB.

Edit: The `--resizefs` is important, without this the `lvresize` command will resize only the volume and not the filesystem on it. If you run `lvresize` without the `--resizefs` option you can resize the filesystem afterwards with `xfs_growfs /dev/mapper/fedora_fedora-root`.

Comment: It’s possibly worth also noting that 15GB is not really all that ‘small’ either for a root filesystem. Not counting application data and swap space, it’s not unusual for a server system to need less than 4 GB of disk space. Fedora will run just fine in that 15GB of space as long as you split out application data properly and make sure old logs are getting cleaned up.

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn so rather than extending the root partition, how could I go about setting a new lvm partition along side it?

Comment: @imrichardcole `lvcreate` is the command to create new logical volumes. From there the new logical volume can be interacted with just like a disk partition, creating a filesystem and setting up either an entry in `/etc/fstab` or a mount unit for it.

Answer (score 2):

LVM is somewhat different from regular partitions. With regular partitions resizing is a PITA because they must be contigious. LVM logical volumes do not have to be contiguous so you can have multiple logical volumes and expand them as and when needed.